# Firebase "Site Not Found" after deploy

Tags: firebase, hosting, firebase-hosting

I am hosting a react project. When I was first deployed the site it was live and all was going good. The problem occured when after some days of deployed, I was trying to reach my site and it's showing "Site not found"! Here is my site link:  https://red-onion-food-restauran-15cfc.firebaseapp.com/
[Site not found issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmT94.png)

Here is how did I configure the firebase hosting initially :

> > I choose firebase hosting for files configuration and optionally select github action deploys
> > I had selected "build" folder as my public directory folder.
> > I choose "Yes" to create a single page application.

I have tried to find a solution of this on google and YouTube but I couldn't get any. I had even deleted the firebase hosting files including "build" folder, and initialized firebase again. But now I have the same issue unsolved. Here I mentioned my firebase.init and .firebaserc file. and attached my build folder asset's screenshot.[buils folder asset's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EL3i.png) Please someone help me get out of this.

.firebaserc file

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "red-onion-food-restauran-15cfc"
  }
}
```

firebase.init file

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```